# How to assign ArrayBuffer Properly from another arrayBuffer in html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a requirement where I have to take a image and render it to hidden canvas. And then read its image data and then slowly render to another canvas using animation.

I have done this :

```
var buffer = null;
var newBuffer = null;
var image = new Image();
image.src = "images/test.jpg"
image.onload = function() {
    render(image);
}
function render(image) {
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    c.width = window.innerWidth * 0.90;
    c.height = window.innerHeight * 0.90;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.90;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.90;        
    var context = c.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    buffer = imageData.data.buffer; // ArrayBuffer
    newBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.byteLength);
    var dataTypedArray = new Uint8Array(newBuffer);
    var actualData = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= image.width; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= image.height*4; j++) {
            dataTypedArray[i + image.width * j] = actualData[i + image.width * j];
        }
        renderImgSlowly(canvas, image, dataTypedArray);
    }
}
function renderImgSlowly (canvas, image, dataTypedArray)  {
    //some animation to render the image slowly line by line
}
```

Above code works but it renders the image slowly in a strange fashion.
I also know that I am doing a mistake in the for loop , can anybody help me to find where I am doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you could describe exactly how strange the fashion is. What happens? What did you *expect* to happen? -- also, note that your call to `renderImgSlowly()` is **inside** the outer `for` loop, which means that you'll do that work once for every row of pixels in the image. Is that really how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Rq : drawImage, in its 9 argument flavor, is a perfect fit to render line by line : easier, faster.

Comment: @Pointy I want to render them line by line , hence I used the for loop like this.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I didn't understand , can you explain

Comment: Assuming canvas and image have the same size, drawing the i-th line of the image is done with : `dstContext.drawImage(srcImage, 0, i, imageWidth, 1, 0, i, imageWidth,1)`